# help with setup of multiple django sites under a single subdomain

Tags: django, apache2, fastcgi

Under the same subdomain, I need to set up several independent sites each running django, these sites are totally separate. Each site should be in its own subdirectory, and these subdirectories have to be password-protected.

for example:

`subdomain.example.com/site1
subdomain.example.com/site2`

I am using apache2 and have a virtual server entry for the subdomain. django is run using FastCGI.

basically, I do not know how to set this up. What do I put in to my <VirtualHost> entry for the subdomain? Usually, for a single django site under a subdomain I would put WSGIScriptAlias pointing to the python script that should be executed, but what do i do for multiple sites?
please help
thanks
konstantin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my configuration:

`<VirtualHost *:12665>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path
    WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/([^/]+) /sites/$1/httpd/django.wsgi
    <DirectoryMatch ^/sites/[^/]+/httpd>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: A warning. WSGIScriptAliasMatch should not be used if you can avoid it. Incorrect use of it will cause SCRIPT_NAME not to be set correctly causing construction of reverse URLs in the application to be wrong. So, be careful if you go down this path.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't separate virtual hosts.

They are separate "locations" (or "directories") within a virtual host.

You'll do something a bit like the following.

```
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/app/site1/public_html
  Alias /media/site1 /opt/app/site1/media
  DocumentRoot /opt/app/site2/public_html
  Alias /media/site2 /opt/app/site2/media

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(media/site1.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^/(media/site2.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/site1(.*)$ /mysite1.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^/site1(.*)$ /mysite2.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

[This is untested, since we use mod_wsgi for this.]